# How to select a drop down item using Selenium in C# from a Listbox with Dynamic (changing) Xpath value on every page load

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation

For my automated test using selenium in C#, I want to select a drop down list item (any) from the **type** field (ref attached image), however since the id's/xpath for selected element getting generated dynamically at every page load,  my selected element click is failing when I run my recorded script.

[image]
For example my below script fail, as XPath "//select[@name='Entries[**db9ef219-0f54-4925-9589-0f39351f44a4**].TypeID']" changes every time as I run test in VS.Net. Value **db9ef219-0f54-4925-9589-0f39351f44a4** changes every time when page loads.

```
IWebElement selectType =
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@name='Entries[db9ef219-0f54-4925-9589-0f39351f44a4].TypeID']"));
        selectType.Click();
```

Here is the page code - on load for each new row a unique value (below it's **c36582c1-131a-4f6f-8711-390048f5779f**) is generated and stored under class **RegEffEntryContainer**, and is used for each list elements - type/description  ( e.g. id="Entries_c36582c1-131a-4f6f-8711-390048f5779f__TypeID",  id= "Entries_c36582c1-131a-4f6f-8711-390048f5779f__Organisation")

[image]

Any help in resolving this would be highly appreciated - thanks in advance!

**FYI**: If I use the below code using Dynamic XPath, it will only work for the first row and I would not be able to record any subsequent row entries via the script. Requirement is to enter all 3 entrees before clicking **Save/Submit** button (not shown on the screenshot above).

```
IWebElement selectType = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@id, '__TypeID')]"));
```

Thank you **@JeffC** for your suggestion - adding the html code as suggested - I've still kept the code image provided earlier.

```
<div class="RegEffEntryContainer" xpath="1">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-11">
      <input type="hidden" name="Entries.index" autocomplete="off" value="21b28f6b-8aaa-4924-815a-1d925585fa36">
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field EntryID must be a number." data-val-required="The EntryID field is required." id="Entries_21b28f6b-8aaa-4924-815a-1d925585fa36__EntryID" name="Entries[21b28f6b-8aaa-4924-815a-1d925585fa36].EntryID" type="hidden" value="391">                
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="field-wrapper">
                       <select class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field TypeID must be a number." id="Entries_21b28f6b-8aaa-4924-815a-1d925585fa36__TypeID" name="Entries[21b28f6b-8aaa-4924-815a-1d925585fa36].TypeID" required="" aria-describedby="Entries_21b28f6b-8aaa-4924-815a-1d925585fa36__TypeID-error" aria-invalid="false">
                          <option value="">Select type</option>
                          <option value="1">Regulatory Activity</option>
                          <option value="2">Major Project</option>
                          <option value="3">Other Activities</option>
                       </select><span class="asterisk">*</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Update[27/02/2019 7:00 PM]**  - since the numeric id's (**value: 21b28f6b-8aaa-4924-815a-1d925585fa36** above) used for TypeID/OrganisationID is dynamically created at page load, is there a way using **Javascript** to record this in a variable at page load and reuse that to create a XPath for element identification later?
[image]

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: @JeffC thanks for your suggestion - I've updated the issue with actual code from the page. As a new user: (1) I struggled to copy the exact required code properly from the page and (2) While pasting the copied code on here, it did not retain the formatting, and I had to spend lot of time to adjust it manually. Any better way to copy and paste?

Comment: I usually just grab what's relevant and then put it into a HTML beautifier like [this](https://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify/) and let it do most of the work. I do have to tweak things from time to time but that should at least save some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be a perfect answer, or the best way to do this, but I was able to solve this issue using **JavaScript**. Used an Array to store the dynamic ids at run time, and later used them to create string to find the required element on DOM. Below is the my code.

```
int numberOfEntriesOnPage = System.Convert.ToInt32(((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.getElementsByName('Entries.index').length"));
string[] array = new string[numberOfEntriesOnPage];
         for (int a = 0; a < numberOfEntriesOnPage; a++)
            {
                String script = "return document.getElementsByName('Entries.index')[" + a + "].value";
                array[a] = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script).ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Array value:" + array[a]);
                string rowTypeID = "Entries_" + array[a] + "__TypeID";

                select_select_by_index(By.Id("Entries_" + array[a] + "__TypeID"), 1);
                IWebElement selectOrg = find_element(By.Name("Entries[" + array[a] + "].OrganisationID_input"));
                selectOrg.Clear();
                selectOrg.SendKeys("3801 LTD");

                IWebElement selectInOffice = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Entries_" + array[a] + "__InOffice"));
                selectInOffice.Clear();
                selectInOffice.SendKeys("10");

                IWebElement selectOffsite = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Entries_" + array[a] + "__Offsite"));
                selectOffsite.Clear();
                selectOffsite.SendKeys("5");

                IWebElement comments = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Entries_" + array[a] + "__Comment"));
                comments.Clear();
                comments.SendKeys(array[a] + "Manish test");

                IWebElement save = find_element(By.XPath("//button[@value='SaveDraft']"));

                save.Click();

            }

public static void select_select_by_index(By by, int index)
    {
        var select = new SelectElement(find_element(by));
        select.SelectByIndex(index);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact count of the row then simply use this

```
IWebElement firstSelect = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@id, '__TypeID')][1]")); 
IWebElement secondSelect = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@id, '__TypeID')][2]"));
IWebElement thirdSelect = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@id, '__TypeID')][3]"));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Waqar. firstSelect.Click() worked fine, however secondSelect.Click() throw error message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[contains(@id, '__TypeID')][2]"}

Comment: Are fields visible on page?? Try to open your chrome inspect element then try to search these XPath. This will show either elements are present on page or not

Comment: Yes, they are visible on the page (created at page load), and are shown as: Entries_9e9589a2-7b11-4155-8520-04231964a4da__TypeID, Entries_50e5a094-8d73-4204-a923-b005e8c7ac3d__TypeID, Entries_4985e37d-60a6-45f5-a43b-4b30e6b4ccd4__TypeID. I can think of using Javascript which can record these numeric values at page load and by storing in some string I should be able to create Xpath, however don't have much expertise in JS.

Comment: try to wait till element is not visible.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("//select[contains(@id, '__TypeID')][2]")));